# Grep options for Regular Expressions. (ERE, BRE, Perl regex) differences

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I am getting the hang of `grep` and regex, but I am confused about the different options.

```
grep --help | grep -i "reg.*ex"
  -E, --extended-regexp     PATTERN is an extended regular expression (ERE)
  -G, --basic-regexp        PATTERN is a basic regular expression (BRE)
  -P, --perl-regexp         PATTERN is a Perl regular expression
```

I have a general knowledge of regular expressions, but often I find myself stumbling on the basics (e.g. Using '*' when it actually requires '.*'), which I blame on not knowing the differences between the **types of regular expressions (ERE, BRE, Perl regex)**.

Is it explained somewhere in detail?

Comment: I have voted to close this as off-topic ("request for tutorial/learning materials").  It would be a too big topic to correctly write in an answer on this site.  [The Wikipedia article on regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) hold much information, as should the `perlre` and `re_format` manuals on your system. See also the "see also" section of your `grep` manual.  Do come back with _specific_ question about any of these type of expressions though.

Comment: see also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y

Comment: @Sundeep: perl's regex are not explained (only pcre) in your link. Perl is the most advanced regex engine ever.

Comment: @GillesQuenot can you clarify? I see links for both pcre and perldoc... and grep uses PCRE (as per GNU grep manual)

Comment: PCRE is not perl, just a subset of perl's regex

Comment: Using '\*' when it actually requires '.\*' sounds lie you're confusing regular expressions and shell globs - rather than different RE flavors.

Answer (score 3):

Answering the specific question about `*`.

The `*` special character in a regular expression (of any type) acts on the previous expression. It allows for zero or more matches of the previous expression. The regular expression `.*` therefore matches any string, whether it's empty or not.

The `*` filename globbing character matches any (possibly empty) string.

Regular expressions are not filename globbing patterns (or vice versa).  This particular difference is between regular expressions and globbing patterns, and not a difference between different types of regular expressions.